# Longtable in two pages

Tags: longtable

I have a table over two pages. Every question of my table is separated with \miderule. However one question is quite long. I want this to span over two pages but because I structured it with midrule it shows up on the next page. Is there any way to fix this.

```
\begin{longtable}[l]{p{.21\textwidth} p{.74\textwidth}}
\toprule
\textbf{Topic}                                                                                                          & \textbf{Question}
                                                                                                                     \\ 

\midrule
Introduction
\\ 
\midrule
Background information & 
Q1. This is a question
\\ 

\midrule
Design & 
Q1. This is a question
\newline  Q2. This is a question
\\
\midrule
Prototype & 
Q3. This is a question
\newline a. Type
\newline b. Type
\newline c. Type
\newline d. Type
\newline e. Type
\newline f. Type**
```

If for instance I want to put c,d,e,f on a new page it doesn't work. Q3 is simply but on a new page fully and doesn't span over two pages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can't split a cell inside an alignment across two pages.

Comment: Thank you, but how? Now Question 4 just begins on a new page.

Comment: That's what I said: you *can't* split a cell across two pages. Do ``\\`` where it's necessary and continue in another row.

Comment: @Dan Please make your example compilable. We can help you better then. A hint: just do a new cell without a `midrule` and write your content-for-the-second-page in there.

Comment: Almost certainly this would be better set as a list rather than a longtable, then page breaking would occur naturally within entries

Answer (score 1):

A cell can not be distributed over two pages. Therefore, you will have to split this manually by putting the next-page-content into a new cell. Without a new `\midrule`, this will not differ from what you have desired.

The `\newpage` in my MWE can be removed. It's just for demonstration purpose.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\null % can be removed
\vfill % can be removed
\begin{longtable}[l]{p{.21\textwidth} p{.74\textwidth}}
\toprule
\textbf{Topic} & \textbf{Question}\\ 
\midrule
Introduction & \\ 
\midrule
Background information & Q1. This is a question\\ 
\midrule
Design & Q1. This is a question\newline  
Q2. This is a question\\
\midrule
Prototype & Q3. This is a question
\newline a. Type
\newline b. Type
\newline c. Type
\newline d. Type
\newline e. Type
\newline f. Type**\\
\newpage % can be removed
& g. Type\newline
h. Type\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]